# add two dictionary into same array swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save two dictionary into one array in swift but I get error because they have different type, is a way to just add generic type, here is my code

```
        var resolved = Dictionary<String,T -> Void>()
        resolved  = [ "fulfill": fulfill]

        var rejectDic = Dictionary<String,NSError -> Void>()
        rejectDic  = [ "reject": reject]

        var test = [resolved,rejectDic]
```

Comment: Where do you get the generic parameter `T`?

Answer (score 2):

A very nice and Swift-y way of doing this is with an enum. It makes a lot of sense if you think about it: You want your test array to contain either type of a dictionary, which is exactly what an enum does. You can declare it like this:

```
enum AcceptanceDict<T> {
    case Resolved([String : T -> Void])
    case Rejected([String : ErrorType -> Void])
}
```

And your code would look maybe like this:

```
class Test<T> {
    func fulfill(t: T) { print("Fulfilled: \(t)") }
    func reject(error: ErrorType) { print("Rejected: \(error)") }

    var test : [AcceptanceDict<T>] = []

    func testSet() {
        let resolved = [ "fulfill" : fulfill ]
        let rejected = [ "reject" : reject ]

        test = [
            .Resolved(resolved),
            .Rejected(rejected)
        ]
    }

    func testGet() {
        for dict in test {
            switch dict {
            case .Resolved(let resolved): break
                // resolved is of type [String : T -> Void]
            case .Rejected(let rejected): break
                // rejected is of type [String : ErrorType -> Void]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just opened a playground to create an example of this with an enum, but you beat me to it 1+

Comment: @nPn Hehe, I too was constantly checking for someone else to post an answer like this :P

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to do this more simply way like this

```
var promiseDic = Dictionary<String,Any>()
promiseDic  = [ "fulfill": fulfill,"reject":reject]
self.request.updateValue(promiseDic, forKey: uuid)
```

But when I take the function out of the dictionary do I need to cast to something in particular. Here is my code for taking out from dic

```
var dictionary:Dictionary<String,Any> = self.request[id] as! Dictionary
    if((error?.isEmpty) == nil){
                    let fun = dictionary["fulfill"]
                    fun(true)
                }else{
                    let rej = dictionary["reject"]
                    rej(NSError())
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Any type. Of course, you will have to cast your dictionaries back to the proper type when you take them out of the array.

```
var resolved = Dictionary<String,T -> Void>()
resolved  = [ "fulfill": fulfill]

var rejectDic = Dictionary<String,NSError -> Void>()
rejectDic  = [ "reject": reject]

var test: [Any] = [resolved,rejectDic]
```

Here is an example of casting when taking the dictionaries out of the array.

```
for dict in test {
    if let resolved = dict as? Dictionary<String,T -> Void> {
        // Do something 
    }
    else if let rejectDic = dict as? Dictionary<String,NSError -> Void> {
        // Do something else   
    }
}
```